# Laravel 5 : test artisan migrate with path

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5

I need a little help please :

With Laravel migrations, I like to put the migration in subfolder.

in a testing class, this works :

```
$this->artisan('migrate:fresh');
```

But, this does not work :

```
$this->artisan('migrate:fresh --path=/database/migrations/v1');
```

Do you have the solution please to specify the path with the tests?

Thank you.

Comment: What does happen? Do you get an error message? Have you tried it without the `/` at the beginning, i.e. `--path=database/migrations/v1`?

Comment: If you are running extra argument on migrate command, you need to remove the `/` at the beginning `--path=database/migrations/v1`

Comment: Without / : Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException: The command "migrate:fresh --path=database/migrations/v1" does not exist.

Comment: This issue still happens, it seems be a persist problem. I tested it in CLI working good but not in tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `artisan` method takes two parameters `($command, $parameters = [])`.

To get this to work you'll need to put the options in the parameters array:

```
$this->artisan('migrate:fresh', [
    '--path' => 'database/migrations/v1'
]);
```

---

Just an FYI, the same is also true for command arguments e.g.

```
php artisan make:model Product -m
```

would be

```
$this->artisan('make:model', [
    'name' => 'Product',
    '-m'   => true,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but not work. This :
$this->artisan('migrate:fresh', [
    'path' => 'database/migrations/v1'
]);
return : Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The "path" argument does not exist.

Comment: @stephweb Sorry, I didn't put the `--` in front of path. I've updated my answer.